# Galilei transformation of mass flux

Tags: fluid-dynamics, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, continuum-mechanics, galilean-relativity

Is it possible to perform a Galilei transformation of a flux without additional information?

Say we consider a flux $q = \rho v$ that can be written as the product of density $\rho$ and a velocity field $v$. Galilei transforming velocities is alright, so we could transform $\frac{q}{\rho}$, but for the flux alone things don't work out: Given the velocity $v$ of a moving frame there will be one choice of density ($\rho = \frac{\left|q\right|}{\left|v\right|}$) such that the flux vanishes after the transformation, i.e. in the moving frame, but for all others it won't.

Does the density always have to be known to perform a Galilei transformation of a flux or is there another way round this?

Answer (score 0):

You need five-vectors to take the Galilei limit of special relativity. Check out Davison Soper Classical Field Theory. He uses the Galilei limit of the NS equation as an example if I remember correctly.